# Select items from arrays of an array with certain indexes

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to select items from each array of arr from index position 0, 2 and 4

**Input array**

```
arr = [
  ["name", "address", "contact", "company", "state"],
  ["n1", "add1", "c1", "cp1", "s1"],
  ["n2", "add2", "c2", "cp2", "s2"] 
]
```

**Output array**

```
arr = [
  ["name", "contact", "company"],
  ["n1", "c1", "cp1"],
  ["n2", "c2", "cp2"]
]
```

Comment: you cannot change the whole question in an edit! Ask a new question if required.

Comment: new_arr = arr.collect { |item| [item[0],item[2],item[3]] } ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". We'd really like to see your attempt to solve this prior to asking. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" Also, you changed your question significantly in an edit. Don't do that because your change makes the answers not match your question, which causes confusion to anyone who is looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 6):

as an alternative to deleting unneeded items, you can just select the needed items.

```
arr.map{|subarray| subarray.values_at(0, 2, 4) }
# => [["name", "contact", "state"], ["n1", "c1", "s1"], ["n2", "c2", "s2"]]
```

Comment: I like. Maybe `arr.map{ |sub| sub.values_at(*(0..arr.size).step(2).to_a) }` for more generality.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: you too seem to infer an imaginary rule from this arbitrary selection of indexes. While the question could benefit from clearer description, it does say "from certain indexes". It does not say "from every other index".

Comment: Rakesh and I had a mindmeld. Actually, I didn't read the question, only other answers. 

Answer (score 5):

If you want tot take this more generic and only select the even columns you could do it like this

```
arr.map{|a| a.select.with_index { |e, i| i.even? }}
```

which gives

```
[["name", "contact", "state"], ["n1", "c1", "s1"], ["n2", "c2", "s2"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Original question:**

> I want to delete items from each array of arr from index position 1 and 5

We can use [`delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) to achieve this. Here:

```
arr.map { |a| a.delete_if.with_index { |el, index| [1,5].include? index } }
# => [["name", "contact", "company", "state"], ["n1", "c1", "cp1", "s1"], ["n2", "c2", "cp2", "s2"]]
```

PS: the output in question is incorrect as for arrays at index 1 and 2, example is deleting element at index 4

Comment: output array isn't containing "state" in my question

Comment: @RakeshPatidar already addressed it in my answer. See I'm not trying to be rude, but changing a question completely in an edit is wrong and you should refrain doing this in future.

Comment: sorry @shivam, I will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also performed with `each_slice` method.

If 0, 2, 4 values can be treated as a list with every second value omitted (`_`), it can be written like:

```
arr.map { |a| a.each_slice(2).map { |item, _| item } }
```

Comment: I very much doubt that this was the original __intent__. Rather, you misunderstood it. Can you imagine a data processing task that starts with "ok, here's a dataset, let's take _every other_ column in it, no matter what it happens to be"?

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. I saw the 0, 2, 4 values and treated them as list with every second value omitted.

Comment: Yup. I've just did that.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has very nice destructuring syntax, so you can extract all your values in a one-liner:

```
a = 0.upto(5).to_a # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x, _, y, _, z = a

x # => 0
y # => 2
z # => 4
```

The underscores are just placeholder for values you don't need.